# How to open Navigation Drawer using espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have tried DrawerActions.open() but it is showing undefined.
Is there any other ways to access navigation drawer ??

Please suggest.

Is something wrong with DrawerActions class of espresso,I am unable to View it.
If you have any thoughts please share.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check if you're missing the **espresso-contrib** library on your build.gradle file.

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
```

If in case you are using `androidx`,

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0'
```

Check other useful espresso extension libraries on the following link - https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/#packages

Answer (score 0):

Try use swipeRight() method from the espresso.
ViewAction.swipeRight();

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html